# jQuery Issue in Internet Explorer IE 8

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I set a global variable, $category_list, which is an array of category names.

In the footer I have:

```
<?php if ( isset($category_list) ): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wordlist = [
            <?php foreach ($category_list as $row) { echo '"' . $row->name . '", '; } ?>
        ];
    </script>  
<?php endif ?>
```

I have an external .js file with the following code:

```
jQuery( ".cats" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(req, responseFn) {
        var matches = new Array();
        var needle = req.term.toLowerCase();

        var len = wordlist.length;
        for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            var haystack = wordlist[i].toLowerCase();
            if(haystack.indexOf(needle) == 0 ||
               haystack.indexOf(" " + needle) != -1)
            {
                matches.push(wordlist[i]);
            }
        }
        responseFn( matches );
    }
});
```

An error occurs in IE8 so the dropdown doesn't work: `wordlist[...] is null or not an object`

Not sure how to get round this, the dropdown list of category names works fine in IE 9, Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't on IE8, affecting around 50% of IE users. I'm using the Codeigniter framework. I've tried loading the footer script before the external file but no joy.

Much love for any help <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 doesn't like trailing `,` in array literal definitions. You'll have to refactor your code to not leave one.

```
<?php 
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($category_list as $row) { $rows[] = '"' . $row->name . '"'; } 
    echo implode(',', $rows);
?>
```

or

```
var wordlist = <?php 
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($category_list as $row) { $rows[] = '"' . $row->name . '"'; } 
    echo json_encode($rows);
?>;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, great fix :-) Just needs $rows[] in place of rows[]